# Overlapping sudoku in Clingo

Tags: sudoku, constraint-programming, clingo

I have written a code in clingo that can generate solutions for sudoku for a single board. (please see the image. Image source: Google)
[image]
My code:

```
% positions
n(1..9).

% assign value for each position
1{initial(X,Y,N):n(N)}1 :-  n(Y), n(X) .

%assign value for each column
1{initial(X,Y,N):n(Y)}1 :- n(X), n(N) .

% assign value for each row
1{initial(X,Y,N):n(X)}1 :- n(Y), n(N).

% defining a subgrid
subgrid(X,Y,Z,W) :- n(X), n(Y), n(Z), n(W), (X-1)/3=(Z-1)/3,(Y-1)/3=(W-1)/3.

% for each subgrid, a number only occurs once
:- subgrid(X,Y,Z,W), initial(X,Y,N), initial(Z,W,N), X!=Z, Y!=W.

#show initial/3.
```

How can I modify it to make overlapping sudoku? Like (please see the image. image source: google)
[image]

Thank You

Comment: Can you can make two completely separate Sudoku puzzles, then constrain the squares in the overlapping regions of each puzzle to be equal to the other one?

Comment: Hi, @ChristopherHamkins Thank you for responding.

 If I copy and paste the same code as well as the input, then I think this will create two sudoku boards, but what should be the constraints? I am stuck here on what constraints can be used to make that.

Comment: Your code here looks like it consists only of comments. Maybe if you edit it and post the complete code it would be easier to answer. Use a code block starting and ending with ``` on a line by themselves.

Comment: If I understand correctly, clingo can enforce equality like this: ``eq (X,Y) :- X == Y, num(X), num(Y).``

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have edited that, and now it's showing as code.

Comment: I also think so. But here, I need to generate two boards. Then how to proceed with that?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherHamkins .

Instead of overlapping code, can you help me determine how many iterations the given code takes to solve for a prefill or no-fill cell?